# How do I recover lost data from a Virtualbox VM that crashed?

Tags: virtualbox, vmdk

My VM from Virtualbox crashed when I attempted a snapshot. Unfortunately I lost some pretty important data as the VMDK was corrupted. The VM then reverted to a prior snapshot on reboot.

I luckily saved the VMDK files prior to restarting the VM and am now trying to recover the data. I've tried mounting the VMDK but when I do it's like the VMDK that gets mounted is the default snapshot from day 1 w/no changes. I configured my VMDK file to be dynamic and be segmented in 2GB chunks as it grows so I'm thinking the changes from these files aren't loading when I mount.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have the Snapshot and all its files. You cloud try to create a clone from the snapshot, when that is done you could try to mount and repair its virtual hard drive. [You also could try merge snapshots by commandline.](https://superuser.com/a/593780/926969)